# Отображение текста с background в safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Есть код который из одного input берет текст и вставляет его в элемент на фото.
В Safari отображается нечто похожее на курсор, указал стрелкой на скрине.
Пробовал caret-color: transparent; - не работает.
Буду благодарен если кто-нибудь подскажет что это и почему!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```html
<center>
<div class="container" id="container">
<p class="right" id="block"></p>
</div>
символы (только латинские)<br> <input type="text" class="input1" name="person" id="input1" 
 onkeyup="input()" pattern="[❤♥⭐★A-Za-z0-9.]{0,4}" maxlength="4">
</center>

<style>
 .container {
  height:300px;
  width:259px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://my.store/IMG_7392.jpg) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  }

.right {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
   background-image: url(https://my.store/IMG_7382.PNG) ;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   }
</style>

<script>
function input() {
  var input_taker = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = input_taker.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```